# C++ - Bool to int conversion bug

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17

I have a function in my code that looks something like this:

```
bool foo(ObjectType& object){

    //code

    const float result = object.float_data + object.bool_data * integer_data;

    //code

}
```

When looking for a bug I found that `result` sometimes have incorrect values and the reason is that sometimes the `bool`*`integer` is calculated as `255*integer` instead of `1*integer`.

C++ says that in an integer context `bool` gets converted to either zero or one so I don't understand this. I multiply with `bool` in other parts in the code and it works fine. Also this is random: sometimes it is converted to `1`, sometimes to `255`. The debugger also shows `true` or `255`, respectively. When this bug happens it always happens in that execution. Recompiling the code has no effect, it still keeps happening randomly.

Comment: Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted. Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Have you tried using an `assert(object.bool_data && object.bool_data == 1)` so see, if you really run into this error, or somebody else does some weird stuff?

Comment: Can you post code (including a `main` function) that reproduces the exact issue?

Comment: please provide variable declarations instead of hungarian-like notation

Comment: It can be a manifestation of UB somewhere else in the code.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That makes sense. That would be very hard to debug though.

Comment: @rubenvb No, the program is 50K+ but I will try to reproduce it with a smaller program.

Comment: @user463035818 The types are simple builtin float, bool, int. No templates or typedefs or literals.

Comment: @Newline thats what i was guessing, but i prefer to see the code. Please read about [mcve]

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I find that QA dump incredibly rude for this question. 1. The question is clear and concise ("why is this behavior guaranteed by the C++ standard not happening in my code") and 2. the asker demonstrably knows how to debug the program - the conclusions are right there in the question. If your point is "can you reproduce this in a smaller program" then just say so. Dumping all the "learn how to ask" links on someone just because they didn't spend hours (or didn't succeed in) trying to reproduce the problem when there might be a simple answer is horrid.

Comment: @MaxLanghof My intention isn't to be rude, but simply to welcome a new user to the site and give good links to read on how to become a productive member and how to write good questions. And the last bit is very important for newcomers, because even if this question isn't very bad for a first question from a brand new member, it's also unanswerable in its current form. All we can really do is give possible workarounds and pointless guessing and speculation. What we can't do is to give a definitive answer about why the OP have this problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude _"simply to welcome a new user to the site and give good links to read on how to become a productive member and how to write good questions"_ -> The site already does this on every corner. Further, idownvotedbecau.se (including "read all of it") is most certainly the opposite of welcoming, so preemptively dumping it on decent questions does more harm than good. Mind you, I'm not implying that you are trying to be rude or that you have ill intentions, just that it comes across as (very) unfriendly. I would suggest to link to MCVE and be done with it if that's your concern.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'd further add that, yes, in this specific example it's not an answerable question, but there are tens of reasons why there could've been a good answer available without a MCVE. It could be a known GCC bug, it could be a misunderstanding of the standard, etc... In those cases, it would be a complete waste of time for the asker to spend hours or days to create a MCVE.

Comment: "sometimes the bool*integer is calculated as 255*integer instead of 1*integer" This cannot happen in a well-behaved program, so either there's a UB somewhere or your compiler has a bug. Can you produce a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inspect where the `bool` is set. Notably, the C++ standard does *not* guarantee that any memory accessed as a `bool` value will convert to `1` if the memory was not exactly `0` - it only guarantees that a `bool` of value `true` will convert to `1`. As mentioned [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.fundamental#footnote-50), it is possible for a `bool` to have a value that is neither `true` nor `false` as a consequence of **undefined behavior**. That may seem obvious (UB after all) but it is also surprising (apparently even by the standard authors' standards).

Here is a practical demonstration of this, using `memcpy`:

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct ObjectType
{
    float float_data = -3.0f;
    bool bool_data = false;
    int integer_data = 2;
};

volatile unsigned char x = 7;

float test()
{
    // Don't actually do this, it is for demonstration only.
    std::array<unsigned char, sizeof(ObjectType)> data = { 0, 0, 0, 0, /**/ x, /**/ 2, 0, 0, 0 };

    ObjectType obj;
    memcpy(&obj, data.data(), sizeof(obj));

    return foo(obj);
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0221a82a6d35e18b <- runtime evaluation yields 14
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/982ff8e4d7503f08 <- compile-time evaluation yields 2

Indeed, [inspecting the binary](https://godbolt.org/g/FmgfVs) shows that `foo` literally interprets the `bool` as an integer and multiplies with it for `gcc`. I would conclude that `gcc` achieves standard conformance by only ever storing a `1` or `0` whenever it stores to a `bool`, thus behaving *as if* `true` is only ever converted to `1` (as long as you never force a `bool` into a diferent state than `true` or `false`).

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense that gcc does that for performance reasons, if it is not initialized then it's UB to use that value, AFAIK.

Comment: This answer is very confusing/misleading. An initialized `bool` is always exactly `true` or `false` which is promoted to always exactly `1` or `0`. It can be _uninitialized_, but it can't be like... `2`.

Comment: @Barry Would you consider the `memcpy` example in my answer a case of an _uninitialized_ bool? That would seem like a misnomer to me. And since `memcpy` is basically the only non-aliasing way of converting e.g. a network packet to structured data, you could theoretically run into this exact issue when sending packets containing `bool` state between different systems.

Comment: @MaxLanghof You're just demonstrating unrelated undefined behavior to OP's apparent problem. Yeah, the assembly generated just multiplies by 7, because you copied an invalid object representation into it. That doesn't change the fact that, per the standard, `bool` cannot be `7`. You just broke preconditions.

Comment: @Barry The point was to exercise what the standard points out itself [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.fundamental#footnote-50). Now, obviously UB is UB and that note is therefore technically redundant, but the fact that the note is still there demonstrates that even the standard authors considered it a very unintuitive consequence of UB that a `bool` can be neither `true` nor `false`. I have edited my post to explicitly mention that UB is required to reach this state.

Answer (score 5):

As per `C++17 7.14 Boolean conversions`, the forcing of a non-boolean to a boolean is part of the standard conversion process, meaning it's actually done when assigning some value to a boolean:

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to `false`; any other value is converted to `true`. For direct-initialization (11.6), a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t` can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`; the resulting value is `false`.

It is *not* guaranteed that the boolean will be zero or one if, for example, you *don't* initialise it, or you initialise it in such a way that it's being treated as a non-boolean:

```
void someFunction() {
    bool xyzzy;              // Set to some arbitrary value.
    memcpy(&xyzzy, "x", 1);  // Very contrived, wouldn't pass my
                             //    own code review standards :-)
}
```

So the *first* thing I'd be looking at is ensuring you *are* initialising/assigning it correctly.

In fact, I very *rarely* nowadays bring a variable into existence without explicitly initialising it to something. Even if it's later changed before use, I'd rather rely on the compiler figuring that out, and optimising if it deems it useful.

---

But you can possibly fix this just by using boolean values as they were intended. In other words, as repositories of truth rather than evaluating them as integral values. Try this instead:

```
const float result = object.float_data + (object.bool_data ? integer_data : 0);
```

That will work whether `bool_data` is:

- a properly initialised boolean;
- an improperly-initialised boolean (though your results will be suspect - what I'm saying is that you'll never get more than one `integer_data` added to your `float_result`); or
- an integral value being *treated* as a boolean (despite this being a bad idea anyway).

Comment: Fixing it is not a problem, I want to know why it happens. Is it a compiler bug or something wrong with the IDE or my code.

Comment: Your IDE does not produce any code, so it can't be responsible for that, your compiler does.

Comment: @paxdiabolo: Code like this is usually employed in branchless programming, which is very common in GPU code.

Comment: Alternatively, fix it by not using `bool` here. Instead use an `int` value of 0 or 1.

Comment: @Khouri: then you have exactly the same problem as the OP found. You should not be using an `int` for something that's fundamentally a true/false value. If you do, and someone sets it to 2, your calculations will be screwed up.

Comment: It’s not the same. A count which might have the reasonable values of 0 or 1 in a certain context is different than assuming what values a compiler considers `true` and `false`.

Comment: Except that here, the question *explicitly* states `bool`, not some count which may be implicitly converted to `bool`. You appear to be commenting on a *different* question :-)

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The bool value was not initialized, so it had 255 (rubish) in it sometimes. I assumed that the bool is converted to 0 or 1 when it is being used in the integer context, instead it is converted to 0 or 1 when it is set from a value. (It was totally my mistake, sorry for wasting your time.)

To sum it up with code:

```
float float_data = 50.0f;
int integer_data = 30;
bool bool_data;

float result;

bool_data = 255;                                //OK
reinterpret_cast<int&>( bool_data) = 250;       //NOT OK

result = float_data + (bool_data ? integer_data : 0);       //OK
result = float_data + bool_data * integer_data;             //NOT OK.
result = float_data + !!bool_data * integer_data;           //NOT OK.
result = float_data + (bool_data == true) * integer_data;   //NOT OK.
```

"OK", meaning it is still wrong but it is at least 0 or 1

Comment: Heh, just as mentioned in my answer, you are running into the exact example the [standard provides](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.fundamental#footnote-50)...

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use the following code then execute it

```
bool foo(ObjectType& object){
    //code
    const float result = object.float_data + int(object.bool_data) * int(integer_data);
    //code
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will make any difference

Comment: It could make a difference. But since the OP's code probably broke because of UB, we can't be sure.

Comment: `b * i` and `int(b) * int(i)` do the same thing.